# .NET 7 minimal API AsParametersAttribute not mapping my request model as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-7.0, minimal-apis

I am trying to implement a simple generic minimal API MediatR method mapper (inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=euUg_IHo7-s)).
I ran into an issue regarding mapping my request model when receiving data from body in the POST method with `AsParametersAttribute`.

I've double checked in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#parameter-binding-for-argument-lists-with-asparameters) that this is possible, but...

- [Using AsParametersAttribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhoCf.png) I don't get any data in the model
- [Using FromBodyAttribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVRK4.png) I get the data in the model as expected.
- [SignInRequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMGTW.png) is a simple model which I've tried to convert to everything - `class`, `record struct`. It doesn't work with `[AsParameters]`. The `IHttpRequest` is just simplification of MediatR's `IResult<TResponse>` with my custom response model.

Comment: Please add sample url you are using and actual code (i.e. `SignInRequest` and the handler code)

Comment: Also please do not post code as images, post it as text. Check out [ask].

Answer (score 3):

[`AsParametersAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.asparametersattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is used to group handler parameters into a single data structure:

> Specifies that a route handler delegate's parameter represents a structured parameter list.

I.e. if you have the following endpoint:

```cs
app.MapPost("sign-in", async (IMediator mediator, SignInRequest request) => ...);
```

This attribute will allow you to introduce a data structure to encapsulate those parameters:

```cs
public struct SignInHandlerParams
{
   public IMediator Mediator {get; set;}

   public SignInRequest Request {get; set;}
}

app.MapPost("sign-in", async ([AsParameters]SignInHandlerParams p ) => ...);
```

It does not replace the `FromBody`, `FromServices` etc. in any way.

Check out the [parameter binding for argument lists with `AsParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?preserve-view=true&view=aspnetcore-7.0#parameter-binding-for-argument-lists-with-asparameters) doc for more details.

Comment: All right, I must've misunderstood. So there is no nice way to use it. I though I could call it from my frontend and just pass in `{ identifier: 'qwe', password: 'qwe' }`, but instead I would have to pass it in with another level of nesting - `{ data: { identifier: 'qwe', password: 'qwe' } }`. I must confess I feel a bit disappointed, but I was too carried away. I will revert my POST and PUT methods to use other attributes. Thank you for the answer. I will try to update the page with my solution once I figure it all out.

Comment: What does SignInRequest look like?